# Single rows of arrows in VectorPlot

Tags: plotting, vector

I have two vector fields which have only one component, e.g. the y-component of the graph below.

How do I obtain a plot similar to the one uploaded here, by using `VectorPlot`? I have trouble plotting a single row of arrows either.

[image]

Comment: Try looking at the `VectorPoints` option.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help, because VectorPoints seems to determine only the number of arrows in the overall plot, not by row and column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try bending `VectorPoints` to your will. I'm not certain whether you have a list of vectors or a function. Using `VectorPlot`:

```
Show[
 {
  VectorPlot[{0, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, \[Pi]}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   VectorPoints -> Table[{x, 1}, {x, 0., \[Pi], \[Pi]/9}], 
   VectorStyle -> Red],
  VectorPlot[{0, x - \[Pi]/2}, {x, 0, \[Pi]}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   VectorPoints -> Table[{x, -1}, {x, 0., \[Pi], \[Pi]/9}]]
  }
 ]
```

[image]